# How to make a list of a single value?

Tags: python

I want to plot x_list and t_list, both have to have the same first dimension, and for now my value of t is just one value. If for example t=4 and dt=0.01, I would like t_list to be a list over values from zero to t=4, with step dt=0.01. It should have the same length as x_list to be plotted. Also, how do I get x_list to take values every dt=0.01? I have put my question in the code:

```
def simulation(dt,t,temp,eta,x,v):

    add_dt=dt
    x_list=[]
    t_list=[]

    sigma=math.sqrt((2*temp*eta)/dt)

#Can I use this? This doesn't give right plotted function I think.
    #while dt<t:
        #t_list.append(dt)
        #x_list.append(brownian(x,v,dt,sigma,eta))
        #dt+=add_dt

#This works, but I would like the x_list to be updated every dt=0.01
    for i in range(0,int(t)):
        x_list.append(brownian(x,v,dt,sigma,eta))

 #This is what I want in the end:
    plt.plot(t_list,x_list)
```

Comment: thank you. My dt=1/1000 in the file, and when I write dt=theline[2] I get error string index out of range. How should I convert this to a float?

Comment: `1/1000` isn't a value, it's an expression that must be evaluated. The result will depending whether an integer or floating point divide is performed.

Answer (score 3):

This will check `theline[0]` is equal to `x` or not. If it is, return `True`:

```
theline[0] == x
```

And this will define `x` as `theline[0]`:

```
x = theline[0]
```

---

And...`f.readline()` will only read **one** line, but `f.readlines()` can read the whole file into a list and split by lines.

---

So your program should be like this:

```
def parameter():
    f = open('parameters.txt','r')
    theline = f.readlines()
    x = theline[0]
    v = theline[1]
    dt = theline[2]
    f.close()
```

Comment: thank you. My dt=1/1000 in the file, and when I write dt=theline[2] I get error string index out of range. How should I convert this to a float?

Comment: `index out of range` means that the list(at this point is `theline`) doesn't have the index `[2]`. For example, `l = [1, 2]`. If you do `l[0]` and `l[1]`,  then you will get `1` and `2`. But if you do `l[2]`, then it will raise ` `index out of range`. Could you edit your question and post your file?

Comment: @mingus1995 I've edited my answer, just replace `f.readline()` with `f.readlines()` :)

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a file, so if you want to put some data from theline into x, v or dt you should use it like this :

```
x = theline[0]
v = theline[1]
dt = theline[2]
```

In this case you only take a char at a time.
Please join an sample of your parameters.txt

Comment: thank you. My dt=1/1000 in the file, and when I write dt=theline[2] I get error string index out of range. How should I convert this to a float?

Comment: Please join a sample off one line of your text file.
You should use `theline.split("")` with the separator into the `""`.

Comment: To convert a string to float you can use `float(string)`

Comment: 0 
0
1/1000
where all values are on new lines. The first is the position, the second the velocity and the third is dt

Comment: Then, try this (i didn't tried it) :
`l = theline.split(" ") 
x = float(l[0])
v = float(l[1])
dt = float(l[2])`

Comment: @MaxD Never post code that you didn't try it. And do you know [what does `Index out of range` mean](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndexError)?

Comment: It was just an example of how to do it. Of course I know the Index out of range. But with the given explanation it seems that there was no problem for an index of 0 to 2.

Comment: I have succeeded now, but if I want to shorten down my function, I want to do something that @MaxD suggested. But then I get error 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. Can I do this in another way? So that I don't need to write all the values first, then convert them to floats separately..

Comment: If you want to have a shorter code you can write somthing like this `x = float(theline[0])` but shorter will be difficult. The `split` method is used with string type (what retruned `f.readline()`) but `f.readlines()` gives you a list of the files lines, not a string.

Comment: But you know, `theline` is a list. Why are you using `theline.split(" ")`? And by the way, @mingus1995 use `floats = [float(i) for i in theline]` to convert them to float.

Comment: In the first version, `readline` was used. So i thougth his file was such a csv one but space separated. That's the reason of the `split`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of your file? One value by line or all values on one line? What is the numeric format of the value?

Your `theline` variable can be seen as an array of chars, so your present code would overwrite your local variables `x`, `v`, `dt` with the values of first characters of each line read from the file. Pretty sure, this not what you want.

Anyway, you can not modify external variables, so your function should return the values read from the file.

Comment: one value per line. I have just put
0
0
1/1000
in my text file on three different lines

Comment: better provide a value that is directly parsable: instead of "1/1000" just write 0.001.

Answer (score 0):

If you replaced the expression on the last line of your `parameters.txt` input file with a value, making this its contents:

```
0
0
.001
```

You could do something like this:

```
import ast

def get_parameters(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return [float(ast.literal_eval(next(f).strip())) for _ in range(3)]


position, velocity, dt = get_parameters('parameters.txt')
print('position: {}, velocity: {}, dt: {}'.format(position, velocity, dt))
```

Output:

```
position: 0.0, velocity: 0.0, dt: 0.001
```

To allow expressions like `1/1000` you could use the built-in `eval()` function instead of `ast.literal_eval()` because the former evaluates arbitrary Python expression. However it would be considered very unsafe since malicious code could be put into the input file and get executed.